# Is there a direct way of addressing a 2D char array and store strings on them in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I want to know whether is there a direct way of addressing a 2D char array and store strings on it.

And I know that by using malloc, I could dynamically allocate memory to strings for example for   `char * names[number]` I can malloc `(char *)malloc(50*sizeof(char))` and get it done.

And also I know that by using a for loop and assigning each and every element you can achieve the same.
I found it through this similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083984/how-to-store-and-then-print-a-2d-character-string-array) .

but my case is ,Is there a way to use array name and indexes to store strings directly.It should look something like this. down here is not a popper code and I just wanted to show how it should look like  (from the link I mentioned above)

```
char arrayOfWords[NUMBER_OF_WORDS][MAX_SIZE_OF_WORD];

int i;`
for (i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_WORDS; i++) {
    arrayOfWords[i] = "laksith"; //here I need to use a way like arrayOfWords+1 etc.
}
```

I think you may have got the idea of what I'm saying.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is 1.

Comment: You need to look at [strncpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy).

Comment: Read the page linked to by @PaulR, then read it again, especially the **warning** part.

Comment: @PaulR Bad advice, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869883/why-is-strncpy-insecure) or simply Google "strncpy is unsafe" for a lot of good reading. Instead, use memcpy and then explicitly add null termination.

Comment: [Even better post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114896/why-is-strlcpy-and-strlcat-considered-to-be-insecure).

Comment: @CarlNorum Yeah that's better but I quoted it from tthe mentioned link. thats why.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  that doesnt help really. what should I get from the warning part.  in to this ??

Comment: @Laksith The warning about that the destination string might, in a corner case, not be terminated, which is kind of important if you going to use the string as, well, a string.

Comment: `strcpy` or `snprintf` are superior to `strncpy`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can. But in this case you need to use `strcpy` instead of the assignment operator:

```
for (i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_WORDS; i++) {
    strcpy(arrayOfWords[i], "laksith"); //here I need to use a way like arrayOfWords+1 etc.
}
```

**UPD:** As @PaulR noted in the comment above, [`strncpy`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy) is a way better option. But first you need to read notes in this link (how to properly handle the missing null byte).

Comment: Why strncpy is better than strcpy ?

Comment: Because it checks for overrun situations.

Comment: @Rudi Not really because No null-character is implicitly appended at the end of destination if source is longer than `size_t n`. Thus, in this case, destination shall not be considered a null terminated C string (reading it as such would overflow).

Comment: But if you think ahead and initialize your array when you declare it, the null-terminating character isn't an issue. (e.g. `char array[6][60] = {{0}};`). You now have the entire array filled with null-terminating chars. As long as you limit your copy to 59 chars, your fine.

Comment: strncpy is not better than strcpy, in fact it is far more dangerous and was [never intended to be a safe version of strcpy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114896/why-is-strlcpy-and-strlcat-considered-to-be-insecure). Don't listen to brainwashed people telling you to use strncpy.

Comment: @Lundin yeah the articles says so.