# Matrix doesn't keep more than one value

Tags: c, arrays, string, for-loop, codeblocks

That is the code:

```
int qtd_alunos, qtd_temas;
char* tnome[1][10];
char* anome[1][10];

printf("\nPra distribuir os temas me diga quantos alunos vao participar e aperte enter, depois a quantidade de temas.");
scanf("%d%d", &qtd_alunos, &qtd_temas);
printf("Agora vai escrevendo o nome de cada tema\n");

for(int j = 0; j<qtd_temas; j++){
    printf("Tema %d\n", j+1);
    scanf("%s", tnome[0][j]);
    printf("%s ok!\n",tnome[0][j]); }
return 0; }
```

When I run the code the program saves just the position `"tnome[0][0]"`, but when the `"int j"` changes to `[0][1]` the program closes. I neeed to understand why it happens.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614249/dynamic-memory-for-2d-char-array) is the answer, also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083984/how-to-store-and-then-print-a-2d-character-string-array) answer will be enough.

Comment: when asking about a run time problem, as this question is doing, post a [mcve]

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the '%s' or '%[...]' input conversion specifiers, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input field.  One less because `scanf()` always appends a NUL byte for those specifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  are  asking  `scanf` to  save  a  string  into  a pointer  that  is
uninitialized. It points nowhere. To fix this, you need to fist allocate
some memory  manually for  your string  and then  set the  pointers. For
example:

```
#define MAX_LEN 101

char *names[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    names[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_LEN);
```

I'm not  sure why you're using  a multidimensional array when  the first
dimension is of size  1. These 2D arrays could be  easily reduced to 1D.
If you meant to  use it as a 1D array of strings  (2D of chars) then use
instead:

```
char names[10][MAX_LEN];
```

Here the first dimension is the amount  of strings and the second is the
size of them. And since it is automatically allocated, you don't need to
do it yourself.

Two important remarks:

- Enable compiler warnings.
- Be careful with buffer overflow: you can limit the size of the string
  read by `scanf` in the format string (i.e. `"%100s"`)

Comment: I removed MAX_LEN and I changed to: tnome[j] = malloc(sizeof(char)); Now it's working very well, and I am using a unidimensional array.

Comment: @ThiagoBarboza you malloc’ed space for a single char. The example `MAX_LEN` was just the size of the string. Use whatever suits your needs.

Comment: I got it. In case I need to write a bigger word at console the program can return an error. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate space for your strings before you read them!

Use `malloc()` to do so (just before reading the input for example), or declare 3D arrays, instead of 2D.