# 2D char array (Storing text with the spacebar in an one char array element?)

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, scanf

Acc. to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083984/how-to-store-and-then-print-a-2d-character-string-array), the most used method to store text in a 2D array is by using %s approach. But, this approach has a downfall, i.e. whenever you press spacebar, the text which is typed after goes into the second element of array. for e.g. you typed

Input:-

1st element of char array = Hi everyone

Output:-

1st element of char array = Hi

2nd element of char array = everyone

Expected output:-

1st element of char array = Hi everyone

So, i want to ask why the below written approach cannot be used to enter text into a 2D array?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
     char ch[20];
     printf("Enter name:");  
     scanf("%19[^\n]", ch);
     printf("Your name is: %s", ch);
     return 0;
}
```

If the above approach can be used, then please let me know how?

Please do not introduce pointer concepts/code in answer to this post. This is a question to understand why the above written approach fails.

Consider this as the code which fails:-

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char name[4][20];
    int i;
    printf("Enter names:-\n");
    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
            printf("Enter name %d: ", i);
            scanf("%19[^\n]", name[i]);
            printf("\n");   
    }
    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        printf("Entered name %d: %s", i, name[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above program compiles without any error or warning, but fails during runtime.

Comment: For the input of e.g. `Hi everyone`, what should the result be? If you have your "2D" array, what should it look like, and after your input what should it contents be?

Comment: *"This is a question to understand why the above written approach fails."* It doesn't fail (at least not for me) and neither is it a 2D array. If it's not working as intended for you, a more detailed problem description is necessary.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Check the post, updated it.

Comment: @Gahlot, if you want to convert "hi everyone" to 2 dimensional with "hi" and "everyone" in seperate string with 0ne scanf function then it is doable as:   char ch[2][20];
     scanf("%s %19[^\n]", ch[0], ch[1]);   but doing so is not recommended as it can overflow the array as per the input.

Comment: @Blaze I am asking when you use the above approach for 2D array it fails then why?

Comment: You still haven't shown the "2d" array itself, or the error messages you get. Please create a [mcve] to show us, and copy-paste the full and complete output from attempting to build that example. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Updated.

Comment: @Deepak please re-read the post and answer again.

Comment: @Gahlot: scanf("%19[^\n]", ch); will read the input till it encounter \n character or 19 character. So it is equivalent to %s with which input read will be a string which is a one dimensional character array, so scanf expect the same. so if you give a 2 dimensional array to this intelligent compiler should give warning/error.

Comment: @Deepak No `"%19[^\n]"` is not the same as `"%19s"`. The `%s` format reads *space delimited* strings. You need the first format to read strings containing spaces.

Comment: First of all, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Use a debugger to catch the crash and find out where in your code it happens. Secondly, `&name[i]` is a pointer to the *array* and not a pointer to the first character of the array. That would be `&name[i][0]` which is the same as `name[i]`. It happens to work because both are pointing to the same location, but they are semantically very different.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: yes, both are not exactly same, how they parse is not same but both expect a char * variable, Please correct me if my understanding is improper

Comment: Furthermore, if you want to read *lines* why don't you use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead? As in `fgets(name[i], sizeof name[i], stdin);`

Comment: @Gahlot:you are passing a 2 dimensional array to scanf,  you can read as scanf("%19[^\n]", name[i]); remove the & in that.

Comment: @Deepak & is not the issue. with/without & your solution fails.

Comment: @Gahlot: got it. this is because you are having '\n' as delimiter, scanf will not remove the delimiter specified, so next scanf will encounter the same again and again. so only first input it prints as it get to first variable, all other will have NULL. this is the behavior of scanf(). if you use %s this will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in the example you provided is that the newline is left in the buffer. You can discard this leading whitespace by changing this:

```
scanf("%19[^\n]", &name[i]);
```

To this

```
scanf(" %19[^\n]", &name[i]);
```

Note the space before `%19`. With this, your program prints:

> Enter names:-
>
> Enter name 0: foo
>
> Enter name 1: bar
>
> Enter name 2: baz
>
> Enter name 3: qux
>
> Entered name 0: foo
>
> Entered name 1: bar
>
> Entered name 2: baz
>
> Entered name 3: qux

This is because the `%[^\n]` specifier tells it to take everything *but* the newline. So the newline will be left in the buffer, and when `scanf` is called again, it is the first thing in the buffer, so those additional calls can't take any input.

That leading space in the `scanf` fixes the problem, because it tells `scanf` to discard any trailing whitespace, which includes that newline left in the buffer.

This is what a [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) says about it:

> **Whitespace character**: the function will read and ignore any whitespace characters encountered before the next non-whitespace
>   character (whitespace characters include spaces, newline and tab
>   characters -- see isspace). A single whitespace in the format string
>   validates any quantity of whitespace characters extracted from the
>   stream (including none).

Comment: Enter names:-
Enter name 0: dss dsfsd

Enter name 1: sdfs dsfsd

Enter name 2: sfs sdfs dsfsd

Enter name 3: dsfs  sdfsdf fss f

Entered name 0: dss dsfsd
Entered name 1: sdfs dsfsd
Entered name 2: sfs sdfs dsfsd
Entered name 3: dsfs  sdfsdf fss f

okay this works. But why a leading whitespace is required specifically.

Comment: You should probably add a note that the `%[` format specifier does not skip leading white-space (like the newline left by previous call).

Comment: @blaze your solution works, but can you explain why a leading whitespace is required??

Comment: @Gahlot I added an explanation on that

Comment: @Blaze yup thanx. Learned a new thing today !

Answer (score 0):

Figured out another approach to get it done.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char name[4][20];
    int i;
    printf("Enter names:-\n");
    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
            printf("Enter name %d: ", i);
            scanf("%19[^\n]", name[i]);     
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("\n");   
    }
    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        printf("Entered name %d: %s", i, name[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fflush` is undefined on input streams. https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fflush.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446297/fflush-function-not-working-with-stdin.